# MySQL multiple table search

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating an online shop where people can upload lessons.

My tables structure for this is

```
products - (contains basic lesson information)
p_tags - id|productid|tag - (contains all tags related to a product)
p_subjects - id|subjectid|productid - (contains all subjects related to a product)
p_years - id|yearid|productid - (contains all years related to a product)
p_types - id|typeid|productid - (contains all subjects related to a product)
subjects - id|name - (contains all subjects links to p_subjects)
resourcetypes - id|name - (contains all product types links to p_types)
years - id|name - (contains all years links to p_years)
```

What I am trying to do is write a query that can generate a `relevance` score based on user search criteria. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
IFNull(a.matchedTags,0) AS matchedtags,
a.title,
IFNull(b.matchedSubjects,0) AS matchedsubjects,
IFNull(c.matchedYears,0) AS matchedyears,
IFNull(d.matchedTypes,0) AS matchedtypes                    
FROM
(
SELECT
z.*,
COUNT(*) AS matchedTags
FROM products z
INNER JOIN p_tags pt ON pt.productid = z.id
WHERE 
pt.tag IN('foo','test')
GROUP BY z.id
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 0
) as a

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
y.*,
COUNT(*) AS matchedSubjects
FROM products y
WHERE
3 IN (SELECT subjectid FROM p_subjects m WHERE m.productid = y.id)
GROUP BY y.id
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 0
) as b ON b.id=a.id

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
x.*,
COUNT(*) AS matchedYears
FROM products x
WHERE
1 IN (SELECT yearid FROM p_years n WHERE n.productid = x.id)
GROUP BY x.id
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 0
) as c ON c.id=b.id

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
w.*,
COUNT(*) AS matchedTypes
FROM products w
WHERE
1 IN (SELECT id FROM p_types o WHERE o.productid = w.id)
GROUP BY w.id
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 0
) as d ON d.id=c.id
```

The query runs fine but will only match a product if the previous criteria is met. I.e if a product has a tag 'foo' then it will then gain a value for number of subjects matched as well. If the product does not contain a tag it will return 0 for all following JOINS.

I'm guessing I'm using the wrong kind of join and have looked into OUTER JOIN using LEFT AND RIGHT then UNION but don't know how to slip this into this code and whether it would work anyway.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to mention the numbers before IN will be my search input as well as the 'foo','test'

Comment: if i have correct understanding about your question, remove the where clause from first join i.e, WHERE 
pt.tag IN('foo','test')...... as this where clause suggests to give the results within these two tags matched..

Comment: How would I then search via an array of tags though?

Comment: I think I definitely need to use an OUTER JOIN but no support for MYSQL :(

Comment: use the where clause at the end of all joins as 
a.TAG IN('foo','test')

Comment: thats not going to work as I need a count for the subjects,years and types. Putting a WHERE at the end is just going to get rid of everything without them particular tags which is not what I want. I want to generate a relevance score using the total of matchedtags,matchedsubjects,matchedyears and matchedtypes which I can then use to sort

Answer (score 0):

What an idiot!! I was joining the joins on top of each other so it was only adding to the criteria above. I have changed it now and working sweeet!!

```
SELECT
    g.title,
    g.id, 
    IFNull(a.matchedTags,0) AS matchedtags,
    IFNull(b.matchedSubjects,0) AS matchedsubjects,
    IFNull(c.matchedYears,0) AS matchedyears,
    IFNull(d.matchedTypes,0) AS matchedtypes                    
    FROM
    (SELECT id,title FROM products) as g

    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    z.*,
    COUNT(*) AS matchedTags
    FROM products z
    INNER JOIN p_tags pt ON pt.productid = z.id
    WHERE 
    pt.tag IN('test')
    GROUP BY z.id
    ) as a on a.id=g.id

    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    y.*,
    COUNT(*) AS matchedSubjects
    FROM products y
    WHERE
    5 IN (SELECT subjectid FROM p_subjects m WHERE m.productid = y.id)
    GROUP BY y.id
    ) as b ON b.id=g.id

    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    x.*,
    COUNT(*) AS matchedYears
    FROM products x
    WHERE
    1 IN (SELECT yearid FROM p_years n WHERE n.productid = x.id)
    GROUP BY x.id
    ) as c ON c.id=g.id

    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    w.*,
    COUNT(*) AS matchedTypes
    FROM products w
    WHERE
    1 IN (SELECT id FROM p_types o WHERE o.productid = w.id)
    GROUP BY w.id
    ) as d ON d.id=g.id
```

Comment: The initial select from products doesn't look like it needs to be a sub query, and not sure why your sub queries are using `IN (SELECT....)` when a join would probably be far more efficient.